# Simplifying Django Query Annotation

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I've 3 models and a function is called many times, but it generates 200-300 sql queries, and I'd like to reduce this number.

I've the following layout:

```
class Info(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

class Forum(models.Model):
    info = models.ForeignKey(Info)
    datum = models.DateTimeField()
    ...

class InfoViewed(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    infokom = models.ForeignKey(Info)
    last_seen = models.DateTimeField()
    ...
```

. I need to get all the number of new Forum messages, so only a number. At the moment it works so that I iterate over all the related Infokoms and I summerize all Forums having higher datum than the related InfoViewed's last_seen field.

This works, however results ~200 queries for 100 Infos.

Is there any possibility to fetch the same number within a few queries? I tried to play with annonate and django.db.models.Count, but I failed.

Django: 1.11.16

---

Currently I'm using this:

```
infos = Info.objects.filter(user_id=**x**)
return sum(i.number_of_new_forums(self.user) \
            for i in infos)
```

and the number_of_new_forums looks like this:

```
info_viewed = self.info_viewed_set.filter(user=user)
return len([f.id for f in self.get_forums().\
            filter(datum__gt = info_viewed[0].last_seen)])
```

Comment: Please add the query that you're using

Comment: Well, it's not one query, but I update the original question.

Comment: What does the method do `get_forums()`. Why do you always taking the zero-indexed item? `info_viewed[0]`

Comment: get_forums() with no parameter returns forum_set.all() and the reason for the zero-indexed item is a wrongly inherited code. There should be always exactly one Info_viewed element for each (User, Info) pair.

Comment: So, what would be the correct direction to start to create this query? Obviously I don't have enough django ORM knowledge to know which way to start.

Comment: I could use something similar then: Info.objects.filter().annotate(noff==Count(Case(When(forum__datum__gt=datum, then=1)))) and summerize the result, however I don't know how to fetch datum value from the related Info_viewed table.

Comment: Or even Info.objects.filter().annotate(noff=Count(Case(When(forum__datum__gt=F('info_viewed__last_seen'), then=1)))) , but the only one problem is that I can't tell to F the correct Info_viewed to use, so which is binded to the current user.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to come up with some solution from a different perspective:

```
Forum.objects.filter(info_id__in=info_ids,
        info__info_viewed__user=request.user,
        datum__gt=F('info__info_viewed__last_seen')).count()
```

where info_ids are all related Infos' id (list), however i'm unsure if it's a 100% procent solution... .

If someone might have a different approach I'd welcome it.